# Does outdated Xcode responsible for crashes of the app?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I had Xcode v6.0 - v6.1 . I'm not sure which one. What I can remember is, it does not support iOS 8.2

The problem is that my team and I release a game app for beta testing ( test flight pre-release , on iTunes connect ) . Every user that got iOS 8.2 crashes at the very beginning when they open up this game app.

After, I upgrade my Xcode to v6.2 which support iOS 8.2. It solve the problem. But still my team and I are not 100% sure if this will solve the problem long term.

My game app framework:
- Cocos2d-x v2.2.6

My question is that:

1.) Is Xcode version the reason it crashes at the first place?

2.) If so, do I need to update my app and my Xcode every time Apple releases new version of iOS?

Thankyou. :)

Comment: Yes it's not support IOS 8.2 for support IOS 8.2 you need to update xcode 6.2

Comment: @NimitParekh that means if Apple release iOS 8.3 for example, will I need to upgrade my Xcode then update my game app on Appstore? Thank you for very fast response :)

Comment: That's not a think but apple can major changes like watch kit integrate and few major release so it may be resolve but when the big changes so must compulsory need to update.

Comment: @NimitParekh, you are posting incorrect information.

Comment: if your code crashes on certain version of iOS, the issue is inside your code somewhere – nothing to do with the compiler, you have probably forgot to support something or ignore some deprecations etc...

Comment: @holex aw.. thankyou I need to check my code then. :) Thankyou very much

Answer (score 3):

You need to investigate exactly what is happening, for example by connecting a device running 8.2 to a development machine and debugging. It is most likely that you have some bug in your code that can strike at any time due to random differences of the environment; for example uninitialised memory will have random values that can be different depending on the OS and will sometimes crash and sometimes not. It is quite possible to have a bug that has nothing to do with OS or Xcode version at all that behaves like this. And that bug can reappear at any time.

Correctly written code will work on all future OS versions without problems. With emphasis on "correctly written".

Comment: This looks more like an extended comment than an answer.  There is no answer without a stacktrace and code.

Comment: @gnasher729 To be more specific, users that has iOS 8.2 run on their device crashes on the FBLoginView. And because Cocos2d-x is written in C++, I need to add wrapper class in objective c++ for FBLoginView. Also there are some warnings on Xcode in between the wrapper class. 

Here is the warning : Instance method '-createFBLoginView' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Is it possible that this warning responsible for the crashes?